# Writing an abstract for a conference

Tags: article-writing, publishing

For the first time, I'm preparing a 2-page abstract, jointly with a faculty member, to submit to a conference in mathematical logic so that the committee can decide if they allow me to present the whole material there.

As an undergraduate student, I did take a course on technical writing, which was not solely about mathematical writing.  While I learned what to include in an abstract in general technical writing, I'm not sure if the general principles apply to a long abstract in mathematics that is not submitted along with the rest of the paper.

(The problem is that I've just graduated from a college and am waiting for the graduate school to start, which means that I'm neither an undergraduate or graduate student and that I'm denied access to university libraries.)

I'd be grateful if you could point out what I should care when writing such an abstract.

Comment: If you have been admitted to grad school, I don't think their librarian would throw you out of their library.

Comment: Or you can do it like the kids at the mall and ask the grown-ups walking by to buy that age restricted game.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've been admitted to a grad school located 370 kilometers away from where I'm currently living. Maybe I should move as fast as possible :-(

Comment: I am afraid that only the "faculty member" you mention above is able to help you. It is very difficult to give advice over the Internet like this.

Comment: Do you still live near your undergraduate university? Since mine lets even non-students into the library, you probably wouldn't be able to take anything out but if so you could use their facilities?